# There exists non Borel-measurable set in $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure, fake-proofs, borel-sets

Show that not all subsets of $[0, 1]$ are Borel-measurable. Find a description of a non-measurable subset ? Hint: use the result about non-existence of shift-invariant
measures on $([0, 1],\mathcal P([0, 1]))$

I struggle to show it because I have shown in a previous exercise ([Singletons are included in Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274968/singletons-are-included-in-borel-sigma-algebra-on-0-1)) that for each $x \in [0, 1]$ we have that
$\{x\} \in \mathcal F[0,1]$. Since singletons are Borel-measurable then any subset $S \subseteq [0,1]$ can be written this way $$S=\bigcup_{x \in S} \{x\}$$
So $S$ is Borel-measurable and it contradicts what the exercise says.

If the exercise is not wrong, then how can I show it ?

Comment: Measurable sets are closed under countable unions, not arbitrary ones

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti my lectures notes say that the union can be uncountable , Wikipedia says that it is countable. I'll speak to my teacher tomorrow. Thanks !

Comment: Do you know enough about the Borel sets to know the cardinality of the collection of Borel sets? Do you know about non-Lebesgue measurable sets such as Vitali sets, Bernstein sets, etc.? It is difficult to determine what would be an appropriate way to deal with your first sentence without more context about your background and what you're allowed to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\mathfrak{c}$ many Borel measurable sets and $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ many subsets of $[0,1]$. So trivially there are many non-Borel measurable sets.